# « Barbesse/Barbès » dans « Joe le taxi » ?

Tags: paroles-de-chanson, toponymes, connotation

Dans le clip [*Joe le taxi*](https://youtu.be/Ulay2FvUEd8) (1987), avant que Vanessa Paradis ne chante, on peut entendre quelqu'un monter à bord et demander (*Barbès*) comme destination, que malhreusement un [moteur](https://www.google.com/search?&q=Joe%20le%20taxi) de recherche vient nous présenter sous le phonétique *Barbesse*.

Peut-on confirmer qu'il s'agit bien de *Barbès* et qu'est-ce que ça évoque immédiatement chez la personne qui connaît Paris ; quel adjectif qualifierait le mieux ce lieu et ce qui est évoqué ?

Comment: Joe le taxi était bien une [chauffeure de taxi parisienne](https://www.leparisien.fr/culture-loisirs/la-femme-qui-a-inspire-joe-le-taxi-chante-par-vanessa-paradis-est-decedee-06-03-2019-8026317.php). La voix demande de se rendre à Barbès. C'est soit le [boulevard Barbès](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boulevard_Barb%C3%A8s), soit la [station de métro](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barb%C3%A8s_-_Rochechouart_(m%C3%A9tro_de_Paris)) qui a [une sortie](https://www.sortiesdumetro.fr/barbes-rochechouart.php) sur le boulevard du même nom, peu importe, la direction est la même pour le conducteur.

Comment: On dit généralement Barbès comme raccourci pour la station Barbès-Rochechouart et le quartier environnant.

Comment: Quand on prend un taxi on demande d'être déposé à un endroit... On dépasse la question posée. Barbès ? C'est un monde en soi. Tiens je t'ai trouvé un [article (podcast)](https://www.lemonde.fr/podcasts/article/2021/04/02/barbes-la-cite-des-gamines-perdues_6075306_5463015.html) qui est accessible aux non abonnés. Et dans [le Parisien](https://www.leparisien.fr/paris-75/paris-le-quartier-barbes-n-en-finit-pas-avec-la-delinquance-25-09-2018-7902387.php), et une [émission déjà ancienne](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/planete-terre/barbes-une-ville-monde) sur France Culture.

Comment: @None Oui, c'est vrai, mais il m'est souvent arrivé de demander au chauffeur de prendre d'abord telle rue qui est à proximité, mais on dirait probablement _prenez d'abord Barbès_. Non, cet aspect-là ne m'intéresse pas linguistiquement parlant. Mais je me dis qu'il doit y avoir une raison d'avoir mis cette rue ou cet endroit en début de chanson. Je me dis que c'est parce que ça donne le ton. Donc je veux connaître ce ton-là. Je vais jeter un coup d'oeil sur ces liens, merci ! J'ai surtout besoin d'un ton _utile_, pas précis, utile au contexte de l'étranger qui écoute la chanson...

Comment: Et  sur un [blog d'habitants](http://actionbarbes.blogspirit.com/archive/2016/11/17/une-situation-qui-n-en-finit-pas-de-se-degrader-3083226.html) du quartier. Et un reportage passé sur [une chaîne d'infos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pn5DfMmehAg) en continu. Et encore [sur Libé](https://www.liberation.fr/societe/2011/11/18/barbes-le-dernier-quartier-ou-on-tchatche_775508/), ça date un peu mais encore vrai.

Comment: Mais Barbés c'est pas la banlieue, c'est Paris ville !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128475/discussion-between-eyla-chu-generis-and-none).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je ne vois pas ce que ça pourrait être d'autre que « Barbès ». *Barbès* est un quartier de Paris dans la partie sud du [boulevard Barbès](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boulevard_Barb%C3%A8s), et particulièrement les alentours de la station de métro [Barbès-Rochechouart](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barb%C3%A8s_-_Rochechouart_(m%C3%A9tro_de_Paris)). C'est en gros le sud-ouest de la [Goutte-d'Or](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartier_de_la_Goutte-d%27Or).

La Goutte-d'Or en général, et Barbès en particulier, était à l'époque<sup>1</sup> un des quartiers les moins chers de Paris sinon le moins cher, et a une forte population immigrante. C'est le stéréotype du quartier mal famé.

Culturellement, « Barbès » et « la Goutte-d'Or » peuvent évoquer un lieu cosmopolite, une criminalité élevée, ou des logements relativement bon marché et souvent en mauvais état, mais pour ça on parle plutôt de la Goutte-d'Or. Barbès spécifiquement est un lieu de traffics (de drogue, de contrefaçons, etc.), mais aussi de commerces parfaitement légaux et pas chers (comme le célèbre [Tati](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tati_(entreprise))).

Dans le contexte de cette chanson, je ne suis pas sûr ce que l'auteur voulait évoquer. Je pense que « Barbès » a été choisi parce que c'est un nom reconnaissable et populaire : on ne va pas à Barbès quand on est riche.

<sup>1</sup> C'est encore largement le cas aujourd'hui.

Comment: **Populaire**, oui, et [Joe](https://www.leparisien.fr/culture-loisirs/la-femme-qui-a-inspire-joe-le-taxi-chante-par-vanessa-paradis-est-decedee-06-03-2019-8026317.php), qui a inspiré les paroles de la chanson, était issue était issue du peuple.